# how to deal with nrows when creating an empty data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Say I want to create a data.table, there are two cases, when I know the number of rows and when I don't know the number of rows.
In case one I can't find anything specific on creating an empty data.table with a certain number of rows.

In case two would it be better to create a one row data.table to begin with or just overestimate the nrows?

EDIT: is there a number of rows parameter?

Comment: In what sense is it empty? Data.tables and data.frames are not built to grow their #rows dynamically, if that's what you have in mind.

Comment: In the sense that it's NA without knowledge of how many rows it has to be only columns.

Comment: For the empty data table you can just initialize with empty columns: `dt <- data.table(x=character(),y=numeric())`. Also for the data.table with known rows/columns, one way (although someone can weigh in if there's a better way) would be to initialize with `NA`. `dt <- data.table(x=as.character(rep(NA,100)),y=as.numeric(rep(NA,100)))`

Comment: I don't see any point to initializing the table before filling it... not really any upside. Maybe show an example. There is no way (that I've ever seen) to modify the number of rows after initialization.

Comment: @Frank sometimes I create an empty data table or dataframe before filling in the values with some sort of `while` or `for` loop and things like that.

Comment: @Hack-R Okay, it might be useful for that, but not for some case where you "don't know hte number of rows", whatever that means, right?

Comment: I would like to know if there is a nrow parameter, I can't find that into the documentation.

Comment: Does filling in with `NA` not work? You could do the code in my comment above and just replace `100` with `nrows` and then define your `nrows` as a separate variable.

Comment: @MikeyMike yes sure, but it's repeated code, isn't it? If you have 100 columns you have to type repNAnrows.

Comment: This is clearly an XY-problem. OP, describe better your situation. As already stated, in R you don't create an empty data.frame and then fill it. I assure you that it will be much more valuable for you to state your original problem, so you could very likely receive a proper R-way to do the task you have in mind.

Comment: It might interest you to know that data.frame has no nrow parameter either and that this question does not make sense for these objects... In @MikeyMike's approach, you could also do `DT = data.table(x=character(),y=numeric())[1:100]` and replace 100 with your nrow.

Comment: @Frank good point, i didn't think about that. I like this solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you know the class of your columns beforehand you could do:

**For an empty data.table**:

```
dt <- data.table(x=character(),y=numeric())
```

If you want to actually add results to your empty data.table you will need to append them (part of the reason why making an empty data.table doesn't make a lot of sense). Something like this:

```
dt <- rbind(dt,data.table(x=1),fill=TRUE)
```

**For a data.table with known rows**:

```
nrow <- 100
dt <- data.table(x=as.character(rep(NA,nrow)),y=as.numeric(rep(NA,nrow)))
```

Alternatively, for a data table with known rows you could use @Frank's method (which I personally prefer because it's slightly shorter):

```
dt <- data.table(x=character(),y=numeric())[1:nrow]
```

Comment: I found out that creating a dt with no rows it's not a good idea because I am not able to add an element to only one column of one row.
dt$x[1]=65
> dt
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: x,y

Comment: Yes, thats because dt$x[1] doesn't exist. With an empty data.table you will have to append your results on. One reason why it doesn't really make sense. Try this: `dt <- rbind(dt,data.table(x=1),fill=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

```
# When you know the number of rows, e.g. 5 rows and 3 columns
DT = data.table(matrix(vector(), 5, 3, dimnames=list(c(), c("Date", "File", "User"))), stringsAsFactors=F)

# When you don't know the number of rows, just start with 1 and add as needed
DT = data.table(matrix(vector(), 1, 3, dimnames=list(c(), c("Date", "File", "User"))), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

There are other, probably less verbose ways of doing this, but I like this approach because you can easily switch out `data.table` for other types like `data.frame` and everything still works.

Comment: thanks, is it necessary to use the construct matrix(vector(),etc... Is it possible to use data.table("col1"=0,"col2=0", nrows=10)? I can't find the right syntax

Comment: @user4050 Using the `matrix` function is just one way, yes. I use this because I can switch out `data.table` for `data.frame` and other things and it still works.

Comment: what is the syntax for number of rows, i tried nrow and nrows, neither works. Thanks

Comment: @user4050 Well in my way of doing it the part that controls the number of rows are those first digits (i.e. 5 and 1) in the second argument of `matrix`. `?matrix` has more detail. I'm not really sure as for other ways of doing it because I always use this, but all of the arguments for `data.table` are listed in `?data.table`. I don't see `nrows` or anything there.

Comment: I think it would be better to give the columns the correct classes (instead of initializing them all to logical). If you try to assign to a subset of rows, `DT[1, File := "file.csv"]` it will coerce to logical. That's why it's generally not recommented to do data.table(matrix()) or data.frame(matrix()) or the same with cbind-ing columns. MikeyMike's suggestion is the standard one.

Comment: @Frank when you populate it with something other than logical it automatically updates the class. For instance, populate it with a string and you get character class. You don't need to specify it up front.

Comment: No. Try it. `DT = data.table(matrix(vector(), 5, 3, dimnames=list(c(), c("Date", "File", "User"))), stringsAsFactors=F); DT[1, File := "file.csv"]`. What you describe only happens if you replace the entire column at once (in which case it "plonks" in the package's lingo). See `?\`:=\``

Answer (score 0):

In case you may want to preserve one data.table column names (calls) to another data.table (undervaluedCalls) **along with class types**, you may use this code:

```
undervaluedCalls <- as.data.table(calls)[0] # copy the column structure of calls
undervaluedCalls <- undervaluedCalls[1:10000] # add 10000 NA rows preseving column classes
```

column names were:

> colnames(calls)
>        [1] "Option"      "Ticker"      "Undl_Price"  "Expiration"  "Days_to_Exp" "Strike"      "Bid"         "Ask"         "Mid_Price"
>       [10] "Last"        "Change"      "Volume"      "OI"

to check the column classes run:

```
sapply(undervaluedCalls, class)
```

For me it was the shortest way creating new data.tables. You can remove empty rows afterwards.